# How to know all nodes process running in the server

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a requirement that to get all node process pids from a server. I know `ps` and all similar ones. But the problem is like pm2 daemons (Actual node process)

```
[root@Gems172 Python]# ps -lef | grep pm2
0 S root       919 29043  0  80   0 - 29260 pipe_w 16:53 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pm2
4 S root      8192     1  0  80   0 - 304940 ep_pol Apr17 ?       14:40:53 PM2 v2.4.0: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)
```

How to detect all these process as node process??? Is there anyway like `/proc` or `/sys` or anyotherway???

Comment: Take a look to `pstree`

Comment: Can you pleasr show one example?? For me pstree also retuning the same. pm2 daemon god

Comment: `├─tmux───bash───node───5*[{node}] ` I get this

Comment: `├─PM2 v2.4.0: God─┬─7*[node /home/GEMS───14*[{node /home/GEMS}]]
        │                 └─9*[{PM2 v2.4.0: God}]`

FOr me this is the output. Pm2 is the pm2 process and the next one is the node process invoked by the pm2. If there is no child process running under that it is not showing anynode there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `which node`

check If the path returned by this command is a soft link or not

Then `/proc/pid/exe` will show the executable file

In my case:

```
/usr/bin/node -> /opt/node-v6.4/bin/node
```

So for all the node process `/proc/pid/exe` will show `/opt/node-v6.4/bin/node`